# Why won't my top menu appear?

Tags: android, menu, google-tv

Im a running my app on  the logitech revue. The menu does not appear up top like it should. Can you point out what I am doing wrong or direct me to some resources.
Here are some specifics.

- Theme: Theme.holo
- android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"
- Device : Logitech Revue

Here are some snippets of the essentials:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      Log.i("MENU","Opening menu");
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
  }
```

In res/menu I have the menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/catalog"
     android:title="Profile info"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


<item android:id="@+id/newvideos"
    android:title="Playlist"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />


<item android:id="@+id/popularvideos"
    android:title="Play Video"
    android:onClick="handleCick"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
 />
```

Comment: I assume by top menu you mean the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)?

Comment: @alextsc , Yes  I want a persistent bar along the top to use for navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the action bar you have to set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or above as stated in [Action Bar - Adding the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding). I suggest you change the targetSdkVersion to stay compatible with lower API levels.

*This is how it works in general, the logitech revue seems to be a google tv device. I have no experience with that, not sure if there are any special things to consider.*

Comment: My program crashes when I change the targetSdkVersion to 11.   E/AndroidRuntime(20263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ameba.api/com.ameba.api.Home}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Fabii You get that because you do network calls on the UI thread. This exception gets thrown by the [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) *([blog post about this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html))*. It's an entirely different issue though. If you can't figure it out from the docs, please post a new question.